# Pass a variable that's part of a URL to a script?

Tags: javascript, json, variables, url

The page for abstract photography on my photo site uses a link like this:

```
myphotosite.com/abstract.html
```

That page uses a script to call on the Flickr API to fetch my photos & info.  It includes a few lines like this:

```
    {
        photo_set: "abstract",
        tags: "best"
    },
```

My site currently has a ton of pages and a ton of scripts (one of each for each photo set).  What I'd like to do is have one page plus variables in the url and one script which uses the variables.  Following the example above, the link would be something like this:

```
myphotosite.com/page.html?variable_1=abstract&variable_2=best
```

And the script would be something like this:

```
    {
        photo_set: "variable_1",
        tag: "variable_2"
    },
```

How do I pass variables in a url on to a script used on that page?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855394/362536

Comment: Thanks, Brad!  You led me to the answer, which I posted in full below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brad posted a link above which led to the answer.  Thank you, sir!  Here it is for anyone who is interested:

Here's the page he linked to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3855394/362536

From there, I found the following code which I added at the top of my script, as follows:

```
// get the variables

 var url_variable = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        var p=a[i].split('=', 2);
        if (p.length == 1)
            b[p[0]] = "";
        else
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```

The part of my original script for using the variables is as follows:

```
{
    photo_set: url_variable["album"],
    tag: url_variable["tag"]
},
```

Thus, if I want an album of my best abstract photos, my url would be:
myphotosite.com/page.html?album=abstract&tag=best

It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to parse the page's URL and extract the query params from it. See the following demo:

```js
// Set this to window.location.href in actual code
let pageUrl = "https://myphotosite.com/abstract.html?variable_1=abstract&variable_2=best";
let url = new URL(pageUrl);

// Construct your object
let obj = {
  photo_set: url.searchParams.get('variable_1'),
  tag: url.searchParams.get('variable_2')
};

console.log(obj);
```

*PS: URL API is not supported on Internet Explorer.*